# How to deploy separate DNS server for email filtering

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010, spam

I'm looking to install Vamsoft ORF as a spam filter for my domain. Looking at the [Deployment Guide](http://vamsoft.com/support/docs/how-tos/deployment-5.3#deployment-on-perimeter) I've noted the following statements regarding DNS.

- The server should not be the same DNS server that supports your Active Directory
  The easiest way to comply with the above is to install Microsoft® DNS Server on the computer where ORF is deployed. This software is part of Windows® Server and can be added as a server role.

Im not sure how to go about implementing something like this. Assuming I install DNS on the HT role of the Exchange Server, how do I utilize that DNS server? Should I be pointing the NIC on the Exchange server to utilize the new DNS server (which does not service the AD domain?) or does the receive connector get set to use that DNS server, while the NIC on the server remains the same as it's always been?

If I change the DNS server on the NIC of the card to a DNS server that does not service AD, will that not break Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not install the DNS role on your Exchange server.
2. Do not configure the Exchange server NIC to use DNS servers other than the DNS servers that service your AD domain.
3. Contact Vamsoft regarding that recommendation to find out exactly what they mean. It's not clear to me from reading the Deployment Guide what DNS servers they're referring to but the Best Practices guide implies that they're referring to the DNS servers that ORF uses (configured within the ORF administration tool), not the DNS servers that the Exchange server uses.